# Implementação Restful de rotas do express não funcionam no servidor

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, restful

Tenho uma API Restful implementada em NodeJS funcionando normalmente localmente, com todas as rotas respondendo, tudo certinho. Porém, ao colocar em produção no servidor da KingHost apenas a rota raiz funciona.

Fiz uma aplicação básica para testar rotas alternativas e também não funcionou.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Time:', Date.now());
    next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("ROOT"));
app.get("/novo", (req, res) => res.send("NOVO"));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 21265, () => console.log("Server is running!"));
```

Alguém já teve algum problema parecido ou estou esquecendo algo?

**EDIT:** Entrei em contato através de um chamado com a equipe da KingHost e eles me responderam que esse tipo de serviço só funciona ao adicionar a porta na URL. Infelizmente não tem outra alternativa ¬¬

Comment: experimente colocar o app.all("*",...) por ultimo

Comment: Não funcionou, ta dando o seguinte erro no servidor: Cannot GET //novo

Comment: tenta gerar um projeto utilizando o [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html), para tentar ver o que você está fazendo de diferente

Comment: Também não funcionou. Tentei subir aplicação do express-generator e ela também não funciona a subrota, apenas a raiz

Comment: qual é o seu host? acredito que não seja um problema na aplicação.

Comment: KingHost. Pois é, também pensei isso. Só que entrei em contato com o suporte e eles disseram que o servidor está normal. O engraçado que se eu colocar a porta do servidor na URL, funciona

Comment: Eu até poderia usar a API utilizando a porta na URL, mas eu preciso da url com https e ao adicionar a porta não consigo acessar

Comment: [Funcionamento de aplicações nodejs na KingHost](https://king.host/wiki/artigo/funcionamento-de-aplicacoes-nodejs-na-kinghost/), substitua `process.env.PORT` por `process.env.PORT_APP`, isto se o seu script de inicialização for `app.js`, se for o `main.js`, tente `process.env.PORT_MAIN`

Comment: não funcionou também =/

Comment: Conferiu se as rotas não estão case sensitive? e configurada como "/Novo" e você está mandando "/novo"

Comment: Sim. Estão todas minúsculas

Comment: Tente configurar a rota em vez de `"/novo"` colocar `"novo"`, pois o erro esta dizendo que a rota `//novo` não existe.

Comment: Já tinha tentado fazer isso e não obtive sucesso

Answer (score 1):

Também passei por esse problema na KingHost, minha solução foi utilizar um hack na api pra poder fazer funcionar as sub-rotas e fazer uso do Router do express.

Percebi que nas requisições no KingHost, é adicionado uma barra a mais nas sub-rotas, vide mensagem de erro Cannot GET //novo e não o padrão que seria Cannot GET /novo, portanto se você fizer um GET em /teste essa requisição chega na api como //teste, mas isso apenas para as sub-rotas a partir da raiz, e não para a raiz. Ex: se a aplicação no painel da KingHost for mapeado para [https://domínio.com/api](https://dom%C3%ADnio.com/api) (meu caso), tudo que chegar em /api/teste vai chegar na aplicação como //teste. Por isso que uma rota "/teste" não funciona, se vc colocar todas as suas rotas como "//rota", funciona, mas não rola refatorar toda a aplicação pra isso.

O pulo do gato foi, se você mapear uma rota principal com o "//" para todo o seu roteamento (daí o uso do Router do express) todas passam a funcionar, inclusive a raiz, pois você vai colocar todas as suas rotas sob o mesmo pseudo endpoint, o "//".

Adaptando do seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var router = express.Router(); // USO DO ROUTER

app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Time:', Date.now());
    next();
});

// ROTAS NO ROUTER E NÃO NO APP
router.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("ROOT"));
router.get("/novo", (req, res) => res.send("NOVO"));

app.use("//", router); // PSEUDO ROTA PRINCIPAL COMO "//" PARA TODO O ROUTER

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 21265, () => console.log("Server is running!"));
```

Sei que sua questão tem 1 ano, mas espero que possa ajudar a outros que tiverem o mesmo problema como nós.

> EDIT: Entrei em contato através de um chamado com a equipe da KingHost e eles me responderam que esse tipo de serviço só funciona ao adicionar a porta na URL. Infelizmente não tem outra alternativa ¬¬

Lendo isso e sabendo o real problema, só prova que esses suportes não sabem nada, rssss!

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do [@Christiano Marques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/155349/christiano-marques), se vc quiser contornar o problema sem os possíveis transtornos de configurar manualmente os certificados ssl para sua aplicação Node e preferir usar o mesmo certificado ssl da hospedagem KingHost, enquanto mantém funcionando em outros ambientes sem precisar colocar as rotas com `//` prefixado, vc pode adcionar ambas as formas ao mesmo tempo.

Por exemplo:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var router = express.Router(); // USO DO ROUTER

app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Time:', Date.now());
    next();
});

// ROTAS NO ROUTER E NÃO NO APP
router.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("ROOT"));
router.get("/novo", (req, res) => res.send("NOVO"));

app.use("//", router); // PSEUDO ROTA PRINCIPAL COMO "//" PARA TODO O ROUTER
app.use("/", router); // Para acesso normal sem dupla barra "//"

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 21265, () => console.log("Server is running!"));
```

(Procurei por esta resposta por muito tempo pois a configuração do https manual na aplicação hospedada na Kinghost utilizando o mesmo certificado ssl gratuito da Hospedagem normal não estava funicionando, MUITO OBRIGADO [@Christiano Marques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/155349/christiano-marques))